# How to shift selected rows to next adjacent column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

```
df3=pd.read_excel(r'may_2019.xlsx',sheet_name='Sheet2')
```

**Here is Sample of my Pandas Dataframe:**

```
+--------------------------+
|           Col1           |
+--------------------------+
| G | 20 mins | 2015       |
| NR | 2                   |
| G  | 11 mins | 302       |
| TV-MA | 44 mins | Apr 30 |
| G | 198                  |
| TV-MA | Apr 30           |
| NR | 2012                |
| NR | 57 mins             |
+--------------------------+
```

> there are some exception in data(i.e: 2,198,302)

**Output Desired for Given Sample :**

```
+--------+----------+------+-------+-----+
| Rating | Duration | Year | Month | Day |
+--------+----------+------+-------+-----+
| G      |       20 | 2015 |       |     |
| NR     |          |    2 |       |     |
| G      |       11 |  302 |       |     |
| TV-MA  |       44 |      | Apr   |  30 |
| G      |          |  198 |       |     |
| TV-MA  |          |      | Jan   |  20 |
| NR     |          | 2012 |       |     |
| NR     |       57 |      |       |     |
+--------+----------+------+-------+-----+
```

Things I've tried

```
df5=pd.DataFrame(df3.Col1.str.split("|").tolist(),columns=['r','d','y'])
indx=df5.loc[df5.d.str.contains('\d{4}')].index
df6.loc[indx,['d','y']]=df5.loc[indx,['d','y']].shift(1,axis=1)
```

then I failed to shift date according to my required table
so I tried to create function but that also not worked.

```
def split_data(input):
    newd=input.split("|")
    if len(newd)==3:
        df['date']=newd[2]
        df['du']=newd[1]
        df['rating']=newd[0]
    if len(newd)==2:
        df['rating']=newd[0]
        if re.findall('\d{4}',newd[1]):
            df['date']=newd[1]
        else:
            df['du']=newd[1]
    return df
```

Things I've tried doen't provide a complete solution for all cases.
 So Does anyone know how to do it with Pandas?

Answer (score -1):

Looking at your inputs, i would first try reading in the data properly - it seems you fail in defining the separators etc. of the excel file

Comment: I have made my sample output by reading all Data and explained exactly the same output I need in the Desired output table. I wondered what else fails you to understand this thing.

Comment: you are reading all columns from excel into one single column in python and then ask for a workaround - when the simple answer is that you should make sure that your excel file is being read-in properly? and if the original data is occupying just one cell for each line in excel, too, then try the "text to columns" function in excel first to have a column for each variable. you can tell excel that | is a separator and have empty spaces be NaN.

Comment: I already did this with excel. I wanted to do this task with pandas to enhance my skills.

Comment: ok i see. try here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html